# Silent install of IBM Data Client server

Tags: database, db2, ibm-data-db2

I am trying a silent install of the IBM Data Server Client on Windows. I am able to make an installation via GUI without any errors. With the silent install I have the following entry in my log file.

> MSI (s) (40:2C) [11:39:25:095]: Product: IBM Data Server Client - DB2COPY1 -- Installation operation failed.
>
> MSI (s) (40:2C) [11:39:25:107]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: IBM Data Server Client - DB2COPY1. Product Version: 11.1.0.1527. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: IBM. Installation success or error status: 1603.

The command used for installation from the path where setup.exe is present

```
 setup /f /l C:\logs\db1.log /u C:\Users\Administrator\my.rsp
```

Any hints how I can do a silent installation of Data Server Client?

**EDIT- Adding the response File**

```
PROD=CLIENT
LIC_AGREEMENT=ACCEPT
FILE=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\
INSTALL_TYPE=TYPICAL

LANG=EN

INSTANCE=DB2
DB2.NAME=DB2
DEFAULT_INSTANCE=DB2
DB2.TYPE=CLIENT
DB2_EXTSECURITY=YES
DB2_USERSGROUP_NAME=DB2USERS
DB2_ADMINGROUP_NAME=DB2ADMNS
RSP_FILE_NAME=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\PROD_CLIENT.rsp
DB2_COPY_NAME=DB2COPY1
DEFAULT_COPY=YES
```

Errors on the trace File

> STRING = An error occurred while trying to open the registry key "Software\IBM\DB2\DISABLEDCA{E7D2BEA2-DF58-46BF-94A4-C40537E312C2}".

I have multiple occurences of similar error in opening registry entry

**EDIT 2**

Log file with trace turned on.

```
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:238]: Note: 1: 1708 
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:238]: Product: IBM Data Server Client - DB2COPY1             -- Installation operation failed.

  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:238]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: IBM Data Server Client - DB2COPY1. Product Version: 11.1.0.1527. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: IBM. Installation success or error status: 1603.

  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:238]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\64a90c.mst
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:238]: Unable to delete the file. LastError = 32
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:253]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:253]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\64a90c.mst
  MSI (s) (0C:68) [16:36:14:253]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
  === Logging stopped: 3/6/2019  16:36:14 ===
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
  MSI (s) (0C:1C) [16:36:14:253]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
  MSI (s) (0C:B4) [16:36:14:253]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
  MSI (c) (FC:58) [16:36:14:269]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
  MSI (c) (FC:58) [16:36:14:269]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
  === Verbose logging stopped: 3/6/2019  16:36:14 ===
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189624/discussion-on-question-by-vini-silent-install-of-ibm-data-client-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue was problems in the Db2 client fixpack.

It always helps to use a current version (latest fixpack) of the relevant IBM-software. This is especially true when trouble symptoms arise that don't seem to have an obvious explanation.  In this case, the latest version of the Db2 data-server client (at time of writing ) was V11.1.4.4 which is available for download from IBM fix central.

Separately, there were two lines that caused the Db2 installer to report errors, they were the "DB2.TYPE=CLIENT"   and "RSP_FILE_NAME=...."  lines.  These errors were not visible in the main logfile  and were only visibly by careful inspection of the tracefile, although these errors did not cause the installation to fail on Windows Server 2012.

For Windows, it's necessary to use the tracefile ( /t  tracefile ) option on the setup command line if you cannot see the error in the logfile.  Linux users will see response file problems directly in the log file.

Beware of false positive error messages in the tracefile - you can see errors in the tracefile even when the installation completes successfully. So always check the main logfile first to see the completion station, and look in the tracefile when you need more details about the error, taking care to review all the errors in the tracefile.  The Windows silent-install tech for Db2 seems less helpful than that for Linux/Unix.